# Rails app cannot navigate to any other page from sign in page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

So I have a rails+backbone.js app that when the user clicks the link to sign in, they can't navigate to any other page by clicking on the links in the header. the header has links back to the homepage which when you hover over the link on the sign in page the bottom left of the browser says the link is pointing to "session/new" when the link should be pointing to the root url ("/#"). Any ideas as to why this happens? My code is as follows:

```
      //application_controller.rb
      class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
      # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception
      helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

      private

      def current_user
        return nil unless session[:token]
            @current_user ||= User.find_by_session_token(session[:token])
      end

      def sign_in(user)
        session[:token] = user.reset_session_token!
      end

      def sign_out
        session[:token] = nil
      end

      def logged_in?
            return true unless session[:token].nil?
            false
      end

      def ensure_sign_in
        redirect_to new_session_url unless logged_in?
      end  

    end





  class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_credentials(params[:user][:username], params[:user][:password])
    if @user
      sign_in(@user)
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:errors] = "Invalid username or password"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url

  end

end
```

//_header.html.erb

```
    <a class="navbar-brand" href= "#">Title
        <!-- <img alt="Brand" src="http://createfunnylogo.com/logo/harrypotter/Expecto.jpg"
        width="200" height="50"> -->
    </a>

    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group" id="bloodhound">
                <div id="the-basics">
              <input type="text" class="typeahead" id="nav-search" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>

         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to 'Home', "#" %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to 'Sign Out', session_url, method: :delete %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'My Profile', "#/users/#{current_user.id}" %></li>
        <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to 'Sign In', new_session_url%></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Backbone start code:

```
    window.App= {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Routers: {},
    initialize: function() {
        App.Collections.businesses.fetch({
            success: function () {
                new App.Routers.Businesses({
                  $rootEl: $("#content")
                });

                if (!Backbone.History.started) {
                    Backbone.history.start();
                  }

            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `@current_user` after you think you've successfully logged in?  Is that getting set correctly?  Also, do you have any `before_filter`s in place?

Comment: I don't have any before filters in place, but I htink current_user is working as the link to the user profile works correctly.

Comment: What is the auth system you're using?  And when (if at all) does `ensure_sign_in` get called?  you might be able to see it in the rails log/console output - if you hit a link and see a `filter chain halted as`, then somewhere there is a before_filter preventing access.  Maybe it's auto included by your auth gem?  Finally, have you looked at the session token in the `ensure_sign_in` method?  Since that is looking at the token (not the @current_user variable), maybe that's where the redirect trigger is happening.

Comment: I'm using my own custom auth system, I'm actually not using ensure_sign_in any more. Do you think the problem has something to do with the fact that my sign in page is rendered by the rails controller, while all my other pages are rendered as backbone views?

Comment: it could be.  If the session doesn't get properly propagated because the secondary page content is js loaded by backbone.  I haven't done much with backbone, but if the sign_in page does a redirect to root, it seems like the session should be setup properly for the secondary pages.  This is kind of why I was wondering about the value of `session[:token]`.

Comment: Can you post your backbone start code?

Comment: I have posted the start code above